# How can I prevent twice call of observe() method in onViewCreated()?

Tags: android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have Fragment where in `onViewCreated()`  requesting data ,
So every time if I return to that fragment it checks if the `mutableLiveData` is empty or not and if it is empty it  requests from server and I am observing that data  in `onViewCreated()`
But if  I navigate to another tab and then return to the same fragment `observe()` calls twice
I don’t want to move requesting method in `onCreate()`  as if the request fails and if I navigate to another tab and return to that again I want to rerequest the data from server.
My question is how can I prevent  call of `observe()`  twice ?
I added `removeObservers()`  in `onDestroyView()`  but it doesn’t help

Answer (score 0):

Android recently introduced the **viewLifecycleOwner** in fragments. By using it your observe method, this will prevent it from being called twice. Do not use activity or fragment object, use the fragments viewLifecycleOwner object instead.
No need to removeObservers().

example code:

```
viewmodel.livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
  // your code here
})
```